# Mocha for same method needs to return 2 different values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-mocha

Using Mocha, I'm stubbing the same method that needs to return 2 separate values.  No matter what I do, it only returns 1 of the 2 values, thus 1 of my rspec tests always fail.  How do I get the stub to return the correct value at the right time?

The code:

```
describe "#method" do
  it "has something" do
    hash = { "allow_sharing" => "1"}
    CustomClass.stubs(:app_settings).returns(hash)
    get 'method', :format => :json
    JSON.parse(response.body).count.should eq(1)
  end
  it "does not have something" do
    hash = { "allow_sharing" => "0"}
    CustomClass.stubs(:app_settings).returns(hash)
    get 'method', :format => :json
    JSON.parse(response.body).count.should eq(0)
  end
end
```

I also tried it this way with a `before` block.  Still no luck.

```
describe "#method" do
  before do
    hash = { "allow_sharing" => "1"}
    CustomClass.stubs(:app_settings).returns(hash)
  end
  it "has something" do
    get 'method', :format => :json
    JSON.parse(response.body).count.should eq(1)
  end
# ... etc.
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `CustomClass.app_settings` immediately after stubbing just to verify it's returning the expected hash?  This might help narrow the problem down and eliminate any doubt that something else is causing your response to have an unexpected count.

Comment: an4rcho, your suggestion did the trick.  The stubbing was working correctly.  The problem was in the `get 'method'` itself.  It was not checking the value correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try using as_null_object if thats available.  so for example for all lines with stubs:

```
CustomClass.stubs(:app_settings).returns(hash).as_null_object
```